# Read google sheet json data into chartjs

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, chart.js

I have a google sheet with simple two columns, one labels and the other is values.

I succeeded to convert it into json, and using such values in tables using the following js

```
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1GnakUnNQvFXjuzMSPnBpU9eufb4SooQLGL2oFc3lfAs/od6/public/values?alt=json", function (data) {

      var sheetData = data.feed.entry;

      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {

        var names = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$names']['$t'];
        var numbers = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$numbers']['$t'];

        

      }
    });
```

And want to use it in a radar chart.js, which I managed to make it work, but only with hardcoded data

```
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};
var chartColors = {
    red: 'rgba(253, 48, 76)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    yellow: 'rgba(240,236,211)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgba(42,105,163)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgba(48,48,50)'
};

var color = Chart.helpers.color;
var config = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "label1",
      "label2", "label3", "label3", "label4", "label5", "label6"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Current level",
      backgroundColor: color(chartColors.red).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
      borderColor: chartColors.red,
      pointBackgroundColor: chartColors.red,
      data: [
        95,
        65,
        74,
        87,
        70,
        78,
        93
      ]
    }, {
      label: "Goal level",
      backgroundColor: color(chartColors.blue).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
      borderColor: chartColors.blue,
      pointBackgroundColor: chartColors.blue,
      data: [
        95,
        80,
        85,
        90,
        89,
        87,
        95
      ]
    }, ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      labels: {
        fontColor: 'white'
      }
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Curent level vs goal',
      fontColor: 'white'
    },
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        fontColor: 'white', // labels such as 10, 20, etc
        showLabelBackdrop: false // hide square behind text
      },
      pointLabels: {
        fontColor: 'white' // labels around the edge like 'Running'
      },
      gridLines: {
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      },
      angleLines: {
        color: 'white' // lines radiating from the center
      }
    }
  }
};

// A plugin to draw the background color
Chart.plugins.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chartInstance) {
    var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#303032';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chartInstance.chart.width, chartInstance.chart.height);
  }
})

window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas"), config);
```

The problem is I can't get them both to work together, in a sense, if I add a new row (label and value), it will update chart, I tried to substitute the data part in the chart code with the variables I created (names and numbers), but it didn't work.
Also, I'm planning to use it with d3 as well not just chart.js, as well as adding new columns, does it work the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remind that [`jQuery.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is executed asynchronously. Therefore you should create the chart only once the data is available and processed to a format suitable for your chart. This can be done if you place code responsible for chart creation inside the `jQuery.getJSON()` success handler (callback function) as follows.

```js
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1GnakUnNQvFXjuzMSPnBpU9eufb4SooQLGL2oFc3lfAs/od6/public/values?alt=json", data => {
  var labels = [];
  var numbers = [];
  data.feed.entry.forEach(e => {
    labels.push(e['gsx$names']['$t']);
    numbers.push(Number(e['gsx$numbers']['$t']));
  });
  new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Current level',
        data: numbers,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(253, 48, 76, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(253, 48, 76)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(253, 48, 76)'
      }]
    },
    options: {
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          title: (tooltipItem, data) => data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index]
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I didn't know it's executed asynchronously, probably why.