# ChartJS passing data dynamically, then passing data into variables

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to figure out how to take the 3 hardcoded variables [index, fieldName, aggType] and pass data in to them from a json file dynamically, and then pass that variable into the (inData) function that I created, and then finally pass those into the charts that I have created. I am not exactly sure how to go about referencing the data and getting it into the variable. I placed my code below. Please, let me know if I can clarify this any, it is a bit confusing. Index name is the ES index, fieldname is the field to aggregate against and aggType is the type of aggregation like count, sum etc...There was a suggested answer to this question, using the forEach option, however, this was not a good fit for my situation, as it would be necessary to pass multiple lines in some queries, or singular lines in others. The forEach option would force us to deal with each option in an individual way. We wanted to be able to pass the query as a whole. Thank you for all your help. The anser I came up with is below.

mainchart.js

```
$('#chartType').change(function(index, val) {
    buildChart($(this).val())

})


function line() {

    let labels = []
    let data = []
    let index = 'issflightplan';
    let fieldName = 'VehicleType';
    let aggtype = 'count';

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/data/issflightplan/VehicleType/count/", function (inData) {
        aggregationName = index + "|" + fieldName + "|" + aggtype
        for (keyNo in inData.aggregations[aggregationName].buckets) {
            labels.push(inData.aggregations[aggregationName].buckets[keyNo].key)
            data.push(inData.aggregations[aggregationName].buckets[keyNo].doc_count)
        }
    // });
    console.log(data)
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(450, 0, 0, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(0,99,132)');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(255,99,132)')
    var gradient2 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 450);
    gradient2.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(0,50,600)');
    gradient2.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(150,0,100)')


    function drillDownChart(click, mydata) {

        if (mydata[0]) {
            var x = mydata[0]['_index'];
            window.location.href = 'https://chart-js.com/'
        }
    };

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',

        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My New Line Chart',
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: gradient,
                borderColor: 'blue',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderDash: [10, 5, 10, 2],
                borderDashOffset: 10,
                borderCapStyle: 'round',
                borderJoinStyle: 'bevel',
                cubicInterpolationMode: '',
                fill: true,
                lineTension: 0.2,
                pointBackgroundColor: ['red', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'pink'],
                pointBorderColor: ['red', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'pink'],
                pointBorderWidth: 3,
                pointRadius: 2,
                pointStyle: 'circle',
                pointHitRadius: 20,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'purple',
                pointHoverBorderColor: 'pink',
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 5,
                pointHoverRadius: 10,
                showLine: true,
                spanGaps: true,
                steppedLine: false

            }, {
                label: ['My New Line Chart 2'],
                data: data.datapoints2,
                // backgroundColor: gradient2,
                borderColor: gradient2,
                fill: false
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {
            onClick: drillDownChart,

            // onClick: updateChart,

            legendCallback: function (line) {
                var text = [];
                text.push('<ul class="legendClass">');
                for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
                    text.push('<li class = style = "background: ' + chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + ' ">');
                    text.push(chart.data.datasets.label[i]);
                    text.push('</li>')

                }
                text.push('</ul>');
                return text.join("");
            },
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: true
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: true,
                fontSize: 16,
                responsive: true,
            },
            plugins: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    // text: obj.title,
                    position: "top",
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: "New Times Roman",
                    fontColor: 'blue',
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    padding: 10,
                    lineHeight: 1.2,
                },
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    //need to be able to pass the options into you from the data
                    position: "bottom",
                    align: 'center',
                    fullWidth: true,
                    // onClick: alertBox,
                    // onHover: changeFontColor,
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 20,
                        fontSize: 10,
                        fontStyle: 'bold',
                        fontColor: 'black',
                        fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
                        padding: 10,
                        usePointStyle: 'circle',

                    },
                    annotation: {
                        annotations: [{
                            type: 'line',
                            mode: 'vertical',

                            value: '18B',
                            borderColor: 'red',
                            borderWidth: 2
                        }],
                        tooltips: {
                            enabled: true,
                            mode: 'index',
                            intersect: false,
                            position: 'nearest',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 132)',
                            titleFontFamily: 'New Times Roman',
                            titleFontSize: 16,
                            titleFontStyle: 'normal',
                            titleFontColor: '#yellow',
                            titleSpacing: 10,
                            titleMarginbottom: 15,
                            bodyFontFamily: 'New Times roman',
                            bodyFontSize: 15,
                            bodyFontStyle: 'normal',
                            bodyFontColor: 'rgb(0,15,132)',
                            bodySpacing: 3,
                            xPadding: 10,
                            yPadding: 10,
                            caretPadding: 5,
                            cornerRadius: 20,
                            // multiKeyBackground: '()',
                            displayColors: true,
                            callbacks: {
                                title: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                                    // Pick first xLabel for now
                                    var title = chartType;
                                    var labels = data.labels;
                                    var labelCount = labels ? labels.length : 0;

                                    if (tooltipItems.length > 0) {
                                        var item = tooltipItems[0];

                                        if (item.xLabel) {
                                            title = labels[item.index];
                                        } else if (labelCount > 0 && item.index < labelCount) {
                                            title = labels[item.index];
                                        }
                                    }

                                    return title;
                                },
                                events: ["mousemove", "mouseout", "click", "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend"],
                                onClick: function (event, arry) {
                                    getcurrentfilter(event, arry)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(data)
})
}
```

mydata.json

```
{

"hits": [...],
    "aggregations": {
        "issflightplan|VehicleType|count":{
            "meta": {...},
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "Progress",
                        "doc_count":77
                    },
          "issflightplan|CrewSize|count": {
             "meta": {...},
                 "buckets": [
                     {
                         "key": "",
                         "doc_count": 32
                     },
```

Comment: You posted your code, which is good, but there's a lot to unpack and it isn't quite clear what your issue is. Can you whittle down the `line()` function to the parts that aren't working?

Comment: Sure, let me do it now, give me just a minute.

Comment: @Will I took out the code that just doesnt matter, and the line() function is just there to establish where I want to be able to pass the data. So, the main component is the variables and the .getJson statement at the top of the line() function. As you can see in the function (inData) I am passing in the data and setting a variable aggregationName. I am placing a small snippet of the JSON file to show the reason for the setup. Then you can see that I have pushed the labels and data,  which I then place into the line() chart function. Only reason I placed that particular code there.

Comment: I guess I'm missing what the issue is. You fetch data from a server. You set up two arrays: `labels` and `data`. You loop through the object that was returned from the server and populate your arrays. Then you pass the `labels` and `data` arrays to the Chart options to create the table. Seems like everything is a-ok.

Comment: @Will I have adjusted this. Please let me know if this is helpful or not. I can adjust it further, if necessary, to make it easier to understand and unpack. Hopefully the addition of the json setup helps to understand the function setup

Comment: I'm unsure what the problem is. As Will pointed out, we can see where you use ajax to get your json dynamically and populate the data and label arrays for the chart.  Are index, field, aggType specified in your json anywhere?

Comment: I think I'm starting to catch on. You don't want to hardcode the aggregation name. You want your chart to display whatever comes back from the server?

Comment: In addition, you can see where I have passed the data, and labels variables into the datasets area of the chart. However, I would need to be able to use the additional, hardcoded variables, in a different way. As shown in the data issflightplan|VehicleType|count is just one type of aggregation. If I needed to use a different aggregation, and pass that data into those variables, I would want to be able to do it. This is the part that I am uncertain about. If I wanted to do that dynamically, how would I go about it.

Comment: @will yes, that is correct. Sorry, I am trying to word it in a easy to understand way, and it seems that I am having a hard time. lol. But, yes, you have the jist.

Comment: Hardcoding those values is not practical for the actual use case.

Comment: @Phaelaxz is any of the additional information helping to understand?

Comment: Ok, this is a data transformation problem. The important bit is the `mydata.json` as input and the shape of the thing you want as output. So, you get the inData from the server. Now you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the aggregate names as an array. Then [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get your `label` and `data` arrays, etc. It's hard to explain in comments. But essentially, you have a few smaller problems that are solvable.

Comment: That is great to hear! Thank you for taking some time to help! Will look forward seeing an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read google sheet json data into chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183572/read-google-sheet-json-data-into-chartjs)

Comment: Not totally, I understand the for statement structure, and mapping through it, setting global variables, ect.. What I am confused about, is how to find each instance of the index, fieldName, and aggtype. It may not have been clear by reading the data snippet, but, it would go from aggregations, to the variables, then into the meta data, then back to another set of variables, then into the meta data. We want to be able to pass any index, fieldName, and aggType into the variables. I am confused on how to set that up. Please let me know if this helps to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post the answer that I came up, and it is working well, and gives the ability to add some different options to the function later on.

```
function line() {

    let labels = []
    let data = []



    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/data/issflightplan/VehicleType/count/", function (inData) {

        let aggregationName = []

        for (aggName in inData.aggregations) {
            console.log(aggName)
            for( bucket in inData.aggregations[aggName].buckets) {
                labels.push(inData.aggregations[aggName].buckets[bucket].key)
                data.push(inData.aggregations[aggName].buckets[bucket].doc_count)

            }
        }
```